# The task factory "RoslynCodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Me and my friend are working on a project in C# ASP.NET and we are using git as version control. I am working on macOS and my friend is working on Windows. It have worked fine until one day ago when we had worked on my friend's computer and pushed the code. Later I tried to make a pull request and when I tried to run the code (that works fine on the Windows computer) I receive this error message:

> /Users/ludvig/.nuget/packages/ikvm.image/8.4.4/buildTransitive/IKVM.Image.targets(9,9):
> Error MSB4175: The task factory "RoslynCodeTaskFactory" could not be
> loaded from the assembly
> "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll".
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.CodeDom, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or
> load a specific file. (0x80131621) (MSB4175) (Monsterarenan)

We are using .net 6 and the IDE is Visual Studio. This is probably a poorly asked question but we both are new to ASP.NET and we did not find anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this error, here are three solutions, please try one by one:

1. The operation could not be completed successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software. Please turn off all protections.
   [image]
2. It may be a problem of path access rights. Please go to the folder where you are located and change the permission of your user name to user ownership in Properties-Security.
3. Open web.config and find the following related nodes.

[image]

Comment out these results and recompile.

Comment: Tried turning off the firewall, and the access rights were read and write. Where can I find web.config on a mac?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used Visual studio for Mac. But in the Windows version of VS you can find the web.config at the bottom of the Solution Explorer.